# How to get depended max value from another max value?

Tags: mongodb

Assume there are documents with following structure in the collection:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("63af57637d4f4258c1ba460b"),
  metadata: {
    billYear: 2022,
    billNumber: 1
  }
},
{
  _id: ObjectId("63af57637d4f4258c1ba460c"),
  metadata: {
    billYear: 2022,
    billNumber: 2
  }
},
{
  _id: ObjectId("63af57637d4f4258c1ba460d"),
  metadata: {
    billYear: 2023,
    billNumber: 1
  }
}
```

I need to get the max value of `billYear` and **within** this year the max value of `billNumber`. So in this example the max year is `2023` and the max value in this year is `1`.

I tried this attempt:

```
Data.aggregate( [ { $max : { billNumber : "$billYear" } } ] )
```

---

*Update*

```
Data.aggregate([{ $group: { _id: null, maxBillYear: { $max: "$metadata.billYear" }}} ])
```

gives me the max year value:

```
[ { _id: null, maxBillYear: 2023 } ]
```

So I would think of running a second query with this year to get the max value for the number. But is it possible to do this directly in a single query?

Comment: You are not getting `billyear` correctly something like this might help 
```data.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            maxBillYear: {
                $max: "$metadata.billYear"
            }```

Comment: @twister_void: thanks, this helped. But how do I get the max billNumber? Do I have to run a second query?

Comment: @twister_void So it is not possible to do this directly in a single mongodb query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as for your first attempt to get the max year you were not accessing value correctly if you try like this it will work

```
Data.aggregate([{ $group: { _id: null, maxBillYear: { $max: "$metadata.billYear" }}} ])
```

Now the second part of your question to get the max value for the number in single query you can try like this

*To get the max bill year from the data*

```
maxBillYear = Data.aggregate([{ $group: { _id: null, maxBillYear: { $max: "$metadata.billYear" }}} ]).first().maxBillYear
```

To get the max value for the number of bills in a year

```
Data.aggregate([{ $group: { _id: "$metadata.billYear", maxBillNumber: { $max: "$metadata.billNumber" }}} ])
```

Yes you can get only max number result on single query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$metadata.billYear",
      maxBillNumber: {
        $max: "$metadata.billNumber"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      _id: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 1
  }
])
```